# making sapply run faster

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, sapply

I am trying to run the code below but it is taking over 2 hours and has not finished. I also tried using unlist(mclapply()) but did not finish either. Basically I am trying to calculate the earth-mover's distance between the matrices inside a 3D array called results2. The 3D array has ~9000 matrices that are 8 x 11.

```
dim(results2)
[1] 8851    8   11

indx <- combn(dim(results2)[1],m=2)
library(emdist)
res <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(indx)), function(i) { 
   x1 <- indx[,i];emd2d(results2[x1[1],,],results2[x1[2],,])})
```

If my code is run on a smaller dataset it works. How can I make this thing run faster? more than 2 hours is just not feasible.

Comment: There are `choose(8851,2) == 39165675` possibilities to compare 2 of the matrices. Is this really necessary? What do you want to do with the resulting vector of more then 39 million numbers?

Comment: You realize `indx` is going to have 78 million numbers?

Comment: The first, very very small example in `?emd2d` runs for me in around 0.01 seconds. You want to do that more than 39 million times. Do the math. If that's the minimum amount of time for a call to `emd2d` then you're not going to speed this up without writing your own (probably compiled) code. Note that a 2, 4 or even 8x speed up from parallelization isn't likely to be enough here.

Comment: How can I optimize this?

Comment: My comment was supposed to imply that you aren't likely to optimize this (much) within R. You may need a different tool.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein I basically want to calculate the earth-mover's distance between all of the nonrepetitive combinations between 8,511 matrices. So for ex: results[1,,] with all ~8500 matrices, then results[2,,], etc.

Comment: You may want to consider whether you really need the distance between all matrices, or whether you can find a solution that could help you limit the matrices you need to compare.  Otherwise see @joran's comment

Comment: The `vapply` function maybe a tiny bit quicker but as others have said this seems like a Sim and there is no need to record every possible combn.